# Navigation Bar For Browsing purpose into some hierarchy

Tags: qt, qml, controls

i am looking for a component name, which its tagged as Navigation Bar in intellij Idea's interface guide, here is how its look like (its in top of intellij idea's interface) [image: Intellij Idea Interface]
in general question is what is name of this component and is there any open source project in any language for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its Called [breadcrumbs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_breadcrumbs).
and here is some [example](https://github.com/armikhael/software-center/blob/master/softwarecenter/ui/qml/BreadCrumbs.qml) in qml .